# why can't I get a smooth rotation when I use OrbitControls with enableDamping

Tags: javascript, three.js, camera

In THREE.js, I want to add an `orbitControls` with `controls.enableDamping=true` to add a kind of inertia to make them feel less stiff. Here is what I did:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0);
  makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2);
  makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }


  function render() {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    // controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();

  function requestRender() {
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  controls.addEventListener('change', requestRender);
  window.addEventListener('resize', requestRender);
}

main();
```

of course it didn't have any inertia at all.When I  uncommented the `controls.update()` in the render function, it just got a little better, with just a little inertia. But when I use a Render Flag to control the render, it works much better:

```js
import * as THREE from 'https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0);
  makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2);
  makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  let renderRequested = false;

  function render() {
    renderRequested = undefined;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();

  function requestRenderIfNotRequested() {
    if (!renderRequested) {
      renderRequested = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
  }

  controls.addEventListener('change', requestRenderIfNotRequested);
  window.addEventListener('resize', requestRenderIfNotRequested);
}

main();
```

The code above is from [this manual](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/rendering-on-demand) of THREE.js, the problem is WHY should I use the `renderRequested` flag to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `renderRequested` boolean flag to avoid an uncontrolled/infinite loop.

In this line of your code:
`controls.addEventListener('change', requestRenderIfNotRequested);`

... you're causing the `requestRenderIfNotRequested` method to be called every time `OrbitControls` emits a `change` event, and you're calling `requestAnimationFrame` inside your `requestRenderIfNotRequested` method, which calls your `render()` function, which calls the `controls.update()` method, which emits another `change` event, which circles back to the beginning of this process causing an uncontrolled/infinite loop.

By "flip-flopping" the `renderRequested` boolean flag, you're making sure that you won't have a request to render a new frame in case there's already one in place being executed.

I understand that might seem a little confusing, but I hope that helps you to think through your whole render cycle.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer. There is one more problem here: the loop **exists** whether the `requestRenderIfNotRequested` exists or not. As you were saying the flag `requestRenderIfNotRequested` just make the frames to be rendered in sequence without overlapping.

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I stop rotating the cube with my mouse, the cube stop rotating like 200 milliseconds without the `requestRenderIfNotRequested` flag. By "flip-flopping" the renderRequested boolean flag, the cube continues rotating like 600 milliseconds just like it has some kind of inertia after I stop rotating with my mouse. I don't know why it happened and how the `requestRenderIfNotRequested` flag helps.

Comment: In my opinion, that Boolean won't help because when I stop rotating with my mouse, the only way to call `requestRenderIfNotRequested ` function is from the `controls.update();` which inside the `render()` function, which means the `requestRenderIfNotRequested` flag is already set to `undefined`. Maybe there is something under the hood of the orbit controls.

Comment: @TimBerg Not exactly under the hood, but in the code you have shown. Once you added the event listener to the `change` event (in: `controls.addEventListener('change', requestRenderIfNotRequested)`, you have requestRenderIfNotRequested being called every time the `change` event happens in your OrbitControls instance (`controls`).

Comment: So why the cube is still moving when I stop touching it?  Obviously the `controls.update()` in the render function still call the event listener when I stop rotating the cube. I just can't understand how it works under the hood to make that cube stop rotating gradually And how the boolean flag `renderRequested` helps it.